# how to hide scratch buffer when starting emacs while opening a file?

Tags: init-file

emacs-25 GUI on Debian.

I set up emacs so that it shows the scratch buffer at startup. However, when I open a file via a file manager with right-click -> open with -> emacs, emacs starts up with a split screen and two buffers: on top the scratch buffer, at the bottom the file buffer. I would like that in this circumstance only the file buffer is shown and not the scratch one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

> I set up emacs so that it shows the scratch buffer at startup.

How did you achieve this? By setting the variable `initial-buffer-choice` to a non-`nil` value or some other means?

> I would like that in this circumstance only the file buffer is shown and not the scratch one.

Usually you can achieve your desired behaviour by leaving `initial-buffer-choice` to its default `nil` value and setting the variable `inhibit-startup-screen` to a non-`nil` value in your `user-init-file`:

```el
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t
      initial-buffer-choice  nil)
```

If this does not work, see the following:

> When I open a file via a file manager with right-click -> open with -> emacs, emacs starts up with a split screen and two buffers

Are you able to replicate this behaviour when manually invoking Emacs from a command-line or a program launcher? For example, try running the following two commands in a terminal emulator:

```sh
$ emacs        # w/o file argument
$ emacs foo    # w/  file argument
```

If the manual Emacs invocation works as desired (i.e. no split screen), then the issue may lie with your desktop environment (e.g. the command-line arguments passed to Emacs in the installed `emacs.desktop` file), though I'd be very surprised if this is the case.

Comment: In my init-file I simply use `(setq inhibit-startup-message t)`. I tried the changes you suggested but the behaviour of emacs remains unchanged, even if I run it from a terminal emulator, with the GUI or without (-nw). Without file argument it shows the scratch buffer, with a file argument it shows a split screen with the scratch buffer and file buffer as I described above.

Comment: @rockemacs I can't replicate this. What happens when you start emacs with the option '-q' or '-Q'?

Comment: the '-Q' option does exactly what I want, it shows the scratch buffer w/o file argument, it shows the file buffer w/ file argument. With the '-q' option instead the screen is split if I give a file argument. So, I suppose there is something else in my init-file that alter the intended behaviour of emacs.

Comment: @rockemacs Actually if the undesired behaviour occurs with `-q` it means there is something in your site lisp (e.g. emacs packages installed via `apt`)  that is causing the issue.